# How to assign an image to a TImage control on run time

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using TImage in my Firemonkey application. I want to assign an image to it at run time. How this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

The picture is specified by the [`Bitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Objects.TImage.Bitmap) property. For instance:

```
Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(FileName);
```

or

```
Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);
```

or

```
Image1.Bitmap.Assign(MyBitmap);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Image1.Picture.Bitmap..." instead of "Image1.Bitmap..."?

Comment: This is FMX rather than VCL, so no

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question lacks many details. You did not state the source of your graphic data. If your bitmap is fetched from a DataBase, consider using `LiveBindings` as well. Just link a Bitmap-containg field of your DataSet with `Bitmap` member of your Image in `LiveBindings Designer`. This will create a LinkPropertyToFieldBitmap (instance of `TLinkPropertyToField` class). The Image will be filled using the data fetched from your DataSet. In the shown case it was a PrototypeBindSource.

[image]